# Pandas: how to read CSV specific columns which doesn't contain header

Tags: pandas

```
usecols = [*range(1, 5), *range(7, 9), *range(11, 13)]
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/weather.csv', header=None, usecols=usecols, names=['d', 'm', 'y', 'time', 'temp1', 'outtemp', 'temp2', 'air_pressure', 'humidity'])
```

I'm trying this but always get
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12]

my data set looks like:

[image]

Comment: try without the `names` argument and see if it goes through? could be that usecols and names aren't interacting well - like maybe it is assigning names first and then your usecols is messing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to a **mismatch** in the **number of columns** designated by `usecols` and the number columns designated by `names`.

#### Usecols:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12]  - 8 columns
```

#### names:

```
'd', 'm', 'y', 'time', 'temp1', 'outtemp', 'temp2', 'air_pressure', 'humidity' - 9 columns
```

Change code so that the **range** in `usecols` ends in `14` rather than `13`:

#### Code:

```
usecols = [*range(1, 5), *range(7, 9), *range(11, 14)]
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/weather.csv', header=None, usecols=usecols, names=['d', 'm', 'y', 'time', 'temp1', 'outtemp', 'temp2', 'air_pressure', 'humidity'])
```

##### Example df output:

[image]